# Unable to exit Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, ubuntu-14.04

I've just installed Hive on my Ubuntu machine (14.04). When I run `hive` in the terminal, it comes up with

```
 Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/nkhl/Documents/apachehive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

which is fine, I guess. Then the Hive shell opens. I haven't learnt Hive (yet) so when i run `quit` to quit the shell, it does nothing.

Here's the version of Hive i am on now:

```
Hive 1.2.1
Subversion git://localhost.localdomain/home/sush/dev/hive.git -r 243e7c1ac39cb7ac8b65c5bc6988f5cc3162f558
Compiled by sush on Fri Jun 19 02:03:48 PDT 2015
From source with checksum ab480aca41b24a9c3751b8c023338231
```

I close the terminal off, to quit the shell. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess you must have forgotten to write **`semi-colon`** at the end of **`quit`**.

Use **`quit`** or **`exit`** to leave the interactive shell as shown below. Notice **`semi-colon (i.e. ; )`**

```
hive> quit;
```

OR

```
hive> exit;
```

Answer (score 12):

Here we can exit from hive shell by the following 3 commands

1.hive>`exit;`
2.hive>`quit;`
As we all know that we can connect to hiveserver2 from `beeline,jdbc-odbc,trift api`.So when you are using beeline shell then the first two commands will not work so its better to use the following command to exit from beeline.

```
!exit
```

no semicolon should be used

Answer (score 5):

You should also be about to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit

Comment: `hive > quit;` and `hive > exit;` didn't work for me. This did though.

Answer (score 3):

This is the right way to quit or exit from hive session.

```
hive> quit;
```

or

```
hive> exit;
```

Not the `;`

Answer (score 1):

You can quit using `Ctrl(key) + C(Key)` or `quit`; at the `hive shell prompt`.
That should work!!

Answer (score 1):

use ctr+c to exit the hive 
or    hive > exit;

Comment: Can you explain how your answer is better than the ones already provided?

Answer (score 0):

Once you type exit without ';' then ctrl+C won't work, in this case you shall directly quit the shell by closing terminal.